# Zip arrays in bash

Tags: bash, join, zip, associative-array

I'm trying to make a tool to install some software on my Raspberry Pi using bash. I use `whiptail` to make some menu's, but I can't figure out how to use arrays and function arguments the right way in `bash`.

My `zip2` function is supposed to take one argument from each array and append them to the `ZIP_ARRAY`. The problem is that it breaks up my long description string gets split up into words.

How do I zip the two arrays to get this output: `ZIP_ARRAY=( "htop" "Interactive system-monitor process-viewer" "apt-build" "Frontend to apt to build, optimize and install packages" )`

```
zip2() {
  unset name desc NAMES DESCR
  name=$1[@]
  desc=$2[@]
  NAMES=("${!name}")
  DESCR=("${!desc}")
  unset ZIP_ARRAY
  for (( i=0; i<${#NAMES[*]}; ++i)); do ZIP_ARRAY+=( ${NAMES[$i]} ${DESCR[$i]} ); done
}

APT_PACKAGES=( "htop" "apt-build" )
APT_DESCRIPTIONS=( "Interactive system-monitor process-viewer"
                   "Frontend to apt to build, optimize and install packages" )

zip2 APT_PACKAGES APT_DESCRIPTIONS
FUN=$(whiptail --title "Raspberry Pi Software Installation Tool" --menu "Software Menu" 17 80 10 --cancel-button Back --ok-button Select \
  "${ZIP_ARRAY[@]}" \
  3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

PS: I also need to zip 3 arrays for which I have a similar problem.
Thanks for any help.

edit: This question is not a duplicate of "[How do I merge two arrays in a zipper like fashion in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721317/how-do-i-merge-two-arrays-in-a-zipper-like-fashion-in-bash)". I currently use the answer proposed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721876/7504386). Although it zips the array in the appropriate manner, the array isn't split up the right way. All the words of ZIP_ARRAY become separate elements e.g. `ZIP_ARRAY=( "htop" "Interactive" "system-monitor" "process-viewer" "apt-build" "Frontend" "to" "apt" "to" "build," "optimize" "and" "install" "packages" )` which is not desirable.

edit2: I found the answer, I only had to insert two double quotation marks around `${DESCR[$i]}`, like this:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#NAMES[*]}; ++i)); do ZIP_ARRAY+=( ${NAMES[$i]} "${DESCR[$i]}" ); done
```