# How to prepend -A, -B, and -C to the names of files in bash? Similar to Python's zip function

Tags: bash, iterator, glob, prepend

I'm trying to do the following in `bash`:

```
>>> import glob
>>> FILES = glob.glob("testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/*_bins")
>>> " ".join(map(lambda x:" ".join(x), zip(["-A", "-B", "-C"], FILES)))
'-A testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/maxbin2_bins -B testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/concoct_bins -C testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/metabat2_bins'
```

I can get to the `FILES` part but I can't figure out how to get the last line.  The reason I want to do this is that sometimes the number of files in `FILES` will be `1-3`.  Hopefully 3, but sometimes it will be 2 or 1.

**My question, how can I essentially prepend `-A`, `-B`, and `-C` depending on how many files are available?**

Maybe this will help:

```
FILES=("testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/concoct_bins" "testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/maxbin2_bins" "testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/metabat2_bins")

echo ${FILES[*]}
testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/concoct_bins testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/maxbin2_bins testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/metabat2_bins
```

I was able to do this:

```
python -c """import glob; FILES = glob.glob('testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/*_bins'); print(' '.join(map(lambda x:' '.join(x), zip(['-A', '-B', '-C'], FILES))))"""
```

but I couldn't figure out how to save it to a bash variable.

Comment: Could you add sample input so we can "play" with our proposed solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in a zipper like fashion in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721317/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-a-zipper-like-fashion-in-bash)

Comment: I checked that link and the solution wasn't clear.  @Nic3500 I've added an array if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
files=("testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/concoct_bins" "testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/maxbin2_bins" "testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/metabat2_bins")
letters=({A..Z})

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do echo "-${letters[$i]} ${files[$i]}"; done
```

Output:

```
-A testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/concoct_bins
-B testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/maxbin2_bins
-C testing_output/test/intermediate/metawrap_output/initial_binning/metabat2_bins
```

Comment: `var=$(for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)); do echo "-${letters[$i]} ${files[$i]}"; done)` thanks!  that was it!